# How do I get rid of the date/author name in the gutter on IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, editor

[image of the thing I want to delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VMuQ.jpg) I somehow enabled this view of the date/author for each line of code. How do i get rid of this? It might help to mention I opened this project in IntelliJ from gitHub desktop.

I've tried looking through the editor settings and removing all the gutter icons. I also tried disabling code author in the inlay hints menu. The date/author tag won't go away.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking at are the Git annotations. To disable them again, right-click the gutter and Select "Close annotations".

For more information, see the docs on [Locate code author (Annotate with Git Blame)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/investigate-changes.html#annotate_blame)﻿

Answer (score 0):

In my current version (2023.2.5), I just left click in the gutter, and they go away.